# CSS3 columns two item behavior

Tags: css, web, cross-browser, multiple-columns

Edit: Well this is weird. I was toying around with it and found that if extend the margin to make a .blockData GREATER than 400px (the width of my columns) then it would add the second item underneath as expected. Otherwise it appends the second item to the right of the first creating the unexpected result. I am satisfied with the answer, but it does seem to be a bit of a hack :/. If anyone has an explanation for the behavior below, I would certainly love to hear it.

Alright I nearly have what I need thanks to the fine folks at stackoverflow. I have been trying to get CSS3 columns to do my bidding. The problem is actually on chrome. In the following page if there is more than three `.blockdata` divs in my columned `.maincontent` container `div` then it acts as expected, but if there are only two `.blockdata` divs in it then it ignores my columns and puts them side by side. This only happens in chrome (I have tested with firefox and IE 10) and only with two items. I have posted a fiddle so you can see what I mean.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NMZhU/

I have a number of divs inside the maincontent div that look like:

```
<div class="blockData">
    <a class="listData" href="#">Activity11</a>
    <a class="listDelete" href="#"><img width="30px" src="http://localhost/view/images/Delete.png"/></a>
    <a class="listEdit" href="#"><img width="30px" src="http://localhost/view/images/Settings.png"/></a>
</div>
```

With css:

```
#mainContent /* The containing div */
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;   
    margin: 10px;   
    column-width: 400px;
    -webkit-column-width: 400px;
    -moz-column-width: 400px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside : avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside : avoid;
    column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
}

.blockData /* The divs inside are all of this class */
{
    position: relative;
    width: 380px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0;
    border: 4px outset grey;
    background: lightgrey;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you delete all the .blockData divs except two then you will see my unexpected behavior (in Chrome only). If there is no way around this then I understand, but I want to be sure before I settle for this.

Comment: which version of Chrome? It seems to be working fine for me in Chrome 30.

Comment: If it is fixed in Chrome 30 then it is probably a bug then.

Comment: Normally I go to the About Google Chrome (chrome://chrome) page to check for updates. My current version (as it says) is 30.0.1581.2.

Comment: Yeah I checked there. Mine is  28.0.1500.95 m and I checked the google docs which seem to say that I am up to date with the stable releases.

I tried to find proper changelog for upcoming releases. If anyone knows where they are then let me know so I can check to see if this kind of bug that they fixed.

Comment: Oops, seems like I am on a Dev version and your version is the latest stable release. It's mentioned in Wiki :)

Comment: Well I just downloaded chrome canary (the dev build of Chrome 30) and I still have the same problem. Can others please confirm this?